# Don't understand the referencing and dereferencing for custom C datatype pointers pointing to an array

Tags: arrays, c

```
typedef struct Graph{
    int n;
    int* arr;
} G;

void main(){
    int size;
    G g1;
    int adjm[3][3]={{1,1,2},{4,5,6,},{3,0,0}};
    g1.arr=adjm;
    printf(" %d",*(*(g1.arr +1)+2));
}
```

This is my C code, I want to play around with custom data structures `struct` and so I declared an integer pointer inside the `struct Graph`. Now I'm creating a static multidimensional array in the `main` function `int adjm[3][3]` . When trying to acess the value from the variable `g1.arr`, I keep getting the following error.

> invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

I don't understand why this erro occurs as `g1.arr` is an integer pointer, and I'm simply using it as a reference to a statically declared multidimensional array `adjm[3][3]`, so shouldnt the dereferencing using `*` work here properly?

Comment: `int* arr;` is a pointer to a one-dimensional array of `int`, you cannot assign a 2-dimensional array to it

Comment: So is the solution for this to use a double pointer? My endgoal is for the `g.arr` to be used as a reference for ndimensional arrays. How do I modify the code so that my  `int * arr` in `Graph` can be used as a reference for an ndimensional array either via static memory allocation, or dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: You can't have a "generic" pointer to an array of an unknown amount of dimensions. You need to have the proper corresponding pointer type at compile time in order to dereference correctly. There may be solutions using `void*` and type casting, but even those require code for all supported dimensions

Answer (score 0):

The line `g1.arr=adjm;` is actually `g1.arr=&adjm[0];` which means `g1.arr` points to element at row 0 and column 0 of the `adjm` array.

Later at the `printf`the code `*(*(g1.arr +1)+2))` can be decomposed as following:

`g1.arr +1` -> This will step one element and point to row 0 column 1 => `&adjm[0][1]`

`*(g1.arr +1)` -> This will get the value at row 0 column 1 which is 1. => `adjm[0][1]`

`(*(g1.arr +1)+2)` --> this will add 2 to the previous value => `(1+2)` => `(3)`

`*(*(g1.arr +1)+2))` will then evaluate to `*(3)` which is illegal code because 3 is not a pointer so the dereference operator `*` can't operate on it.